# Question about proof of Browder, Minty Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

Could someone please assist with the following question:

Refer to the [following post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090734/using-lemma-in-proof).

Answer (score 0):

Since $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are fixed, the vector $c^n$ is simply the vector of the components of $u_n$ in the basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Thus, considering the vector $u_n$ or $c^n$ is completely equivalent.